# Combobox binding not working when window is in grid container

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, window

I try to bind a list in `ComboBox` with this code :

```
var template = new DataTemplate();
var comboBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
template.VisualTree = comboBoxFactory;
Binding b = new Binding();
b.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, this.GetType(), 1);
b.Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext");
comboBoxFactory.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
comboBoxFactory.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding("ClassRoom"));
```

It's working when I launch the window simply, like this :

```
winListOrgane ee = new winListOrgane();
ee.Show();
```

But when I try to put this window in a grid container, it's not working :

```
_currentWindow = (ModelPage)Activator.CreateInstance(pPage.GetType());
_currentWindow.SetParam(genParam);
_currentWindow.InitPage();

object content = _currentWindow.Content;
_currentWindow.Content = null;
_containerPage.Children.Add((UIElement)content);
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks

Best regards,
Frederic

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is your `RelativeSource` on the `Binding`. Since you are binding to a specific `Window` class - in this case it looks like `GetType()` will return `typeof(winListOrgane)`. If you change that to `typeof(Window)`, it should work:

```
b.RelativeSource = 
    new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(Window), 1);
```

Comment: In fact this combobox is in a column of my datagrid, and this datagrid have a different datacontext than my combobox.

Comment: Okay, well, hopefully the first paragraph will fix your issue then!

Comment: nothing fix my problem! I don't understand! I try with a simple comboxox but it is the same problem!

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer to be clearer about what I meant. Does that help?

Comment: I think it's the way how I load my window. I try the same code but instead window I try with usercontrol and it's work! you know why I have this behavior?

Comment: Well, it is likely that your `UserControl` has the correct `DataContext`, but the `Window` doesn't.